# Javascript. OnClick Image src +1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, onclick

This is my code:

```
<img name="changer1" alt="before" src="img/.../1/before.jpg"/>
<img name="changer2" alt="after" src="img/.../1/after.jpg"/>

<img src="img/next.png" onclick="changer1.src='img/.../2/before.jpg'; changer2.src='img/.../2/after.jpg'"/>
```

So when I click on the "next.png" image, both pictures change to the pictures in the new folder. This works perfect. But what I want is, when I click on the "next.png" image, the src code automatic change. So when I click it looks like:

```
<img src="img/next.png" onclick="changer1.src='img/.../3/before.jpg'; changer2.src='img/.../3/after.jpg'"/>
```

When i click again it looks like:

```
<img src="img/next.png" onclick="changer1.src='img/.../4/before.jpg'; changer2.src='img/.../4/after.jpg'"/>
```

So the folder allways move +1. From 2 to 3. From 3 to 4...

I hope you know what I mean and help me :)

And sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it with basic DOM methods in Javascript. Firstly I should point out 'name' is a depreciated attribute, HTML 5 uses the 'id' attribute instead.

Anyway firstly we need to add some labels to the img's so we can find them in JS

```
<img id="changer1" alt="before" src="img/.../1/before.jpg"/>
<img id="changer2" alt="after" src="img/.../1/after.jpg"/>
```

I just used your existing name attributes. Figured that was why you'd included them anyway! Then we add a JS function to attach to the on click listener.

```
<script>
var pictureID = 1;
function moveToNextImage(){
    pictureID++;
    var string = 'img/.../'+pictureID;
    document.getElementById('changer1').src = string + '/before.jpg';
    document.getElementById('changer2').src = string + '/after.jpg;
}
</script>
```

This script keeps a counter for the folder value and uses that to generate a new source string to replace the old one with. The function adds 1 to the counter then changes the src attribute on the 2 elements to the new one.

Your next button should look like this to use the function instead.

```
<img src="img/next.png" onclick="moveToNextImage()"/>
```

Comment: Same problem here like I have with Raj's script

Comment: I've read your comment on Raj's script but it sounds like your asking why the other script you haven't shown us doesn't work? Could you include a more complete example in the question?

Comment: I addet a new answer. Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Okey so my problem now is I have **[this](http://www.catchmyfame.com/catchmyfame-jquery-plugins/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/)** script allready installed for those 2 images

So my full script is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.beforeafter-1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#container').beforeAfter();
});
</script>

<div id="container">
 <div><img id="changer1" alt="before" src="http://www11.pic-upload.de/12.09.14/oha2eiilhnay.jpg"/></div>
 <div><img id="changer2" alt="after" src="http://www11.pic-upload.de/12.09.14/gdbsfgzsh2f.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

I hope you know what my problem is...

When I remove the "container" ID from the div, the script from Raj works perfekt. But not my time comparison script, you find in the 1 link.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img name="changer1" id="changer1" alt="before" src="img/.../1/before.jpg"/>
<img name="changer2" id="changer2" alt="after" src="img/.../1/after.jpg"/>

<img src="img/next.png" id="test"/>
</body>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 2;
    $("#test").click(function(){
        var srcbefore='img/.../'+i+'/before.jpg';
        var srcAfter="img/.../"+i+"/after.jpg";
        $("#changer1").attr("src",srcbefore);
        $("#changer2").attr("src",srcAfter);
        console.log(srcbefore+"::"+srcAfter);
        i++;
    });
});

</script>
</html>
```

hope this solves your problem..
FYI - 
Dont couple your JS code in HTML. Make it seperate.
Use Class or ID instead of name.

Comment: in jq, you have to wrap all your code inside $(document).ready(function(){}).

Comment: In your given example waiting for `ready` event is not necessary.

Comment: This works very good but there is still a new problem.
These 2 images are in another script. A time comparison script...
So I need to have them in a div with id "containier"

<div id="container">
<div><img id="changer1" alt="before" src="img/.../1/before.jpg"/></div>
<div><img id="changer2" alt="after" src="img/.../1/after.jpg"/></div>

And script is like this:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $('#container').beforeAfter();
});
</script>

So when I remove the "container" id from the div, your script works, but not my other script...

Comment: A note: a `script` tag must not be a child of `html` you need to move it into the `body` to be valid `html5`.

Comment: @t.neise placing them in head is usually better practise, keep it separate from the display parts of your html

Comment: can you include complete example plz

Comment: I addet a new answer. Hope you can help me :)